# MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices Error

Tags: mysql, .net, entity-framework

I tried all solutions of this problem. I use MySQL Connector Net 6.9.11 and all the latest version of MySQL Data, MySQL Data Entity and Entity Framework from Nuget Solution. But I get this error:

> Inheritance security rules violated by type: 'MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration'. Derived types must either match the security accessibility of the base type or be less accessible.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.TypeLoadException: Inheritance security rules violated by type: 'MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration'. Derived types must either match the security accessibility of the base type or be less accessible.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In order to effectively help you, we need to reproduce the problem you described.